# How to get String from one api and use it to get Data from another Api?

Tags: reactjs, json, api, react-query

I'm using two APIs the dictionary API and the synonym API the application is working well but I'm having to implement a certain functionality which is when the user clicks on the synonym at the bottom it should update the word. I'm using react Query to get the results.
here is a picture of a UI so you can get the idea of what I'm trying to do
[image]

every time the word state changes react query refetches the new word.

here is my Word.jsx
:

```
const Word = ({ fetchWord, fetchsynonym }) => {
  const [word, setword] = useState("run");
  let synarray = [];

  const { data, status, isLoading, isFetching, isError } = useQuery(
    ["definition", word],
    () => fetchWord(word)
  );
  const {
    data: Sdata,
    isLoading: Sloading,
    isFetching: Sfetching,
    isError: Serror,
  } = useQuery(["synonym", word], () => fetchsynonym(word));

  // const handleSynoToWord = (item) => {
  //   setword(String(item));
  // };

  function getsynonym() {
    if (Sloading || Sfetching) {
      return <h2>is loading</h2>;
    } else {
      if (Serror) {
        return "error";
      } else {

        synarray.push(Sdata["noun"]["syn"][0]);

        synarray.push(Sdata["noun"]["syn"][1]);

        synarray.push(Sdata["noun"]["syn"][2]);

        console.log(synarray);
      }
    }
  }

  const getDefinition = () => {
    if (isLoading || isFetching) {
      return <h2>is loading</h2>;
    } else {
      if (isError) {
        return "error";
      }
      let definiton = data[0]["meanings"][0]["definitions"][0]["definition"];
      getsynonym();
      return definiton;
    }
  };

  const handleTranscript = (transcript) => {
    if (transcript.length == 0) {
      console.log("emt");
    } else {
      setword(String(transcript));
      console.log(transcript);

      getDefinition(String(transcript));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isError == false ? (
        <>
          {/* this is just a string you can put it in a heading */}

          <VStack w={"100%"}>
            <>
              <Heading mt={"10%"} textAlign={"center"}>
                {" "}
                hi Welcome to WordUp dont know how to spell a word and want to
                know what it means ? Click below.
              </Heading>
              <Flex
                padding={2}
                boxShadow={"0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)"}
                borderRadius={10}
                flexDir={"column"}
                w={"50%"}
                h={[700, 500, 300]}
                alignItems={"center"}
                justifyContent={"space-around"}
              >
                <Heading> Word: {word}</Heading>
                <Heading padding={10} alignSelf={"center"}>
                  {getDefinition()}
                </Heading>
                {/* <ul>{getsynonym()}</ul> */}
                {/* make background all words */}
                <Synonyms synonymarray={synarray} setword={setword} />
                <Voice
                  handleTranscript={handleTranscript}
                  setword={setword}
                  word={word}
                />
              </Flex>
            </>
          </VStack>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          {getDefinition()}
          <Heading>{word}</Heading>
          {/* <VoicetoText setword={setword} word={word}/> */}
          {setword("run")}
          <Voice
            handleTranscript={handleTranscript}
            setword={setword}
            word={word}
          />
          Hi there was an error so just retry make sure you only use one word
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Word;
```

and here is my synonyms.jsx
:

```
import React from "react";

const Synonyms = ({ synonymarray, setword }) => {
  // im sending the full api request i need to strip the extra even data.somehing is attached so its not the word its data.word there for sending the fill rqueste

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {synonymarray.map((item, i) => (
          <li
            onClick={(item) => {
              setword(item);
            }}
            key={i}
          >
            {item}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default Synonyms;
```

as you can see I store the synonyms in an array and pass them to the synonyms component where I map it out but when I click on the synonym to try to change the word it throws an error which is
[image]

this error has to do with me sending a full API request to another API I believe but I'm not sure which way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be caused by passing the event handler parameters to your `word` state.
Just passing the string item will be enough.

This is something Typescript would see and fix ;)

```js
{synonymarray.map((item, i) => (
  <li
    // not using onClick parameters
    onClick={() => {
      setword(item);
    }}
    key={i}
  >
    {item}
  </li>
))}
```